# Swift filter nested array of objects

Tags: swift

I have an array of Business objects. Each Business object contains an array of key-value pairs, one element of which can be a nested array of ContentBlocks objects.

```
var masterArray = [
        Business(busName: "Dave's Cafe", busId: 1, website: "http://www.davescafe.com", latLong: (45.541, -45.609),
            actions: [["title": "About Us", "contentId": "123", "actionType": "content"],
                ["title": "Website", "url": "http://www.davescafe.com", "actionType": "web"]],
            contentBlocks:[
                ContentBlock(busName: "Dave's Cafe", busId: 1, contentId: "123", title: "Testola!", body: "Hello there!")
            ]),
        Business(busName:...
]
```

I can filter the array to return a specific Businesses matching a unique `busId` by using something like this:

```
let rtnArray = masterArray.filter{$0.busId == id}
    if rtnArray.count == 1{
        return rtnArray[0]
    } else {
        return // feedback that no matches were found
    }
```

Additionally, I'd like to return a specific contentBlock by filtering on the unique `contentId` (if necessary I can also pass the `busId` of the Business 'owner'). I'm really struggling to move forward so any pointers in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution to what I think you're asking:

```
 var contentBlocks = masterArray
                         .flatMap{$0.contentBlocks}
                         .flatMap{$0}
                         .filter{$0.contentId == "123"}
```

Outputs a `[ContentBlock]` containing all `ContentBlock` objects that match the filter from within all `Business` objects.

1. The first flatMap makes the list of `Business`es into an `[ContentBlock?]`
2. The flatMap flattens the `[ContentBlock?]` into a `[ContentBlock]`
3. The `[ContentBlock]` is filtered

Comment: thanks for a great answer. When I try it the compiler complains: `Value of type '[ContentBlock]' has no member 'contentId'` on the last line. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well if contentID is a key it would be written like `$0["contentId"]` to access the value of that key. Compiler is giving you error because it is currently being accessed like a property which I assume it is not.

Comment: @NSGangster Thanks - I tried that but it complains again, this time with `Cannot subscript a value of type '[ContentBlock]' with an index of type 'String'` So I tried without quotes - same error...Hmmm!

Comment: Mocking this up would take me a while (i'd need to make those structs and what not). Could you tell me the type you get after map, and then the type you get after flatMap?

Comment: Sorry try `$0.contentBlock["contentId"]` . If that doesn't work you can try calling `valueForKey("contentId")`

Comment: @NSGangster `ContentBlock` is a struct, not a `Dictionary`. Neither of those will work

Comment: @Amomchilov then why is his compiler saying it can't access contentId? Should it perhaps be `$0.contentBlock.contentId` instead of `$0.contentId` ? It is kind of hard seeing how to access all the properties when I don't understand his data structure.

Comment: Because `$0` is `[ContentBlock]` ... which means `Array<ContentBlock>`. An array of `ContentBlock` is still an Array, it doesn't contain a `contentId`

Comment: @James please answer my question

Comment: @AMomchilov - sorry I wasn't ignoring your Q...was just trying to figure out how to give you the answer (my Swift newbie skills + spinning brain isn't helping).

Comment: just chop off the filter and flatmap part, and see the output, then add back in the flatmap part

Comment: After map: `[Optional([containerTest.ContentBlock(busName: "Dave\'s Cafe", busId: 1, contentId: "123", title: Optional("Testola!"), body: Optional("Hello there!"), type: Optional("generic"))]), Optional([]), Optional([]), Optional([]), Optional([])]`    and    After flatmap: `[[containerTest.ContentBlock(busName: "Dave\'s Cafe", busId: 1, contentId: "123", title: Optional("Testola!"), body: Optional("Hello there!"), type: Optional("generic"))], [], [], [], []]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114256/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-james).

Comment: In case it helps anyone in the future the final solution (provided by @AMomchilov in chat) was to add an additional .flatMap{$0) to yield: `var contentBlocks = masterArray 
.map{$0.contentBlocks} 
.flatMap{$0} 
.flatMap{$0} 
.filter{$0.contentId == "123"}` Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

When you are dealing with model and want to search the nested custom object of class.

Here is class example.

```
public final class Model1  {
// MARK: Properties

public var firstname: String?
public var lastname: String?
public var email: String?
public var availabilities: [Availability]?
public var username: String?
}

public final class Availability {
var date: String
var day : String

init(date: String, day: String) {
    self.date = date
    self.day = day

    }
}
public final class AvailData {
var am: String?
var pm: String?

init(am: String?,pm: String?) {
    self.am = am
    self.pm = pm
   }
}
```

let make an array of Model1.

```
var arrData = [Model1]()
```

In my case, I want to search in availabilities array. So I put below logic and it work perfectly.

```
 let searchData = arrData.filter({ singleObj -> Bool in
     let result = singleObj.availabilities?.filter({ $0.date == "2019/09/17" })
     return result?.count > 0 ? true : false
 })
```

This swift code will return only those records which match `2019/09/17`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// The busId and contentId you want to find
let busId = 1
let contentId = "123"

let contentBlocks = masterArray.flatMap {
    $0.contentBlocks.filter { $0.busId == busId && $0.contentId == contentId }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37730229/131385 is what I was thinking might be possible (only requires the contentId). Your suggestion will be perfect for a similar but slightly different data structure + filter I need elsewhere in my app.